# "Indeed" or "However"

Tags: conjunctions

> If the solar surface, not the center, were as hot as this (20,000,000
>   degrees Celsius), the radiation emitted into space would be so great
>   that the whole Earth would be vaporized within a few minutes.  [*However*/*Indeed*], this is just what would be happen if some cosmic giant
>   were to peel off the outer layers of the Sun.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`However` is used to illustrate a different point.

Since both your cases have the same outcome, `however` isn't appropriate.

Go with `indeed`

Comment: @JooseokLee: If you found it helpful, please accept the answer by clicking on the green check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think either one works well here.  I would simply say:

- This is just what would happen. . .

(not *would be happen*)

btw: Interesting imagery, the "cosmetic giant"  (doing a gigantic face peel?)  I wonder whether the author might have meant a **cosmic** giant.

Also, that's not what would happen; at least not for long. A much-smaller sun would have much less mass, thus much less gravity, thus the pressures that promote fusion would be less, and it would not "burn" so hot.But that's a question for the Physics, Sci-fi or World Building SE.